# Viewpager style is not recognized on tablets

Tags: android, android-viewpager, tablet

I'm almost done with an app and I am about to test it on different devices. Everything looks fine except my viewpager on some devices. I styled it so changed some values from the original ones (mostly colors) but i.e. I test it on tablet (samsung galaxy tab emulator), it recognizes the colors of the original viewpager. Now, I created the layout-hdpi, layout-xhdpi folder as well as the values-v11, values-v14 folders (colors.xml etc) but nothing changes. I also tried it on other pc emulators but I experience the same issue. Did I forget to create another folder which is defined for tablets only, and this is why it gets the data from the simple vales folder?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the color settings in `/values-sw600dp`, which would apply to only tablet sized devices. Settings in values-v11 or values-v14 would apply to all qualified devices with the right OS version regardless of screen size.